# Are sharkfin melon shoots really edible?

Tags: greens, melon

I read that the shoots of sharkfin melons ([*Cucurbita ficifolia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_ficifolia)) are edible. Isn't that kind of unique for a cucurbit? Is it true that they're edible? Are the mature leaves/vines poisonous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a number of sources, the shoots are indeed edible, however all references I found were to "young" shoots, so I don't know about the mature vine itself.

[The Curious Gardener](http://www.curiousgardener.com/2012/05/29/welcome-shark-fin-melon-plant/) says

> It's not just the melon that is edible on this plant; the flowers,
>   leaves, shoots and seeds are also eaten.

Although the flowers, leaves and shoots are mostly used raw as salad greens, 
[The Food and Agriculture Organization of The United Nations](http://www.fao.org/docrep/t0646e/T0646E0a.htm) adds:

> The young stems (called runners), and also the flowers, are eaten
>   as a cooked vegetable.

This
[North Carolina State University Article](http://cuke.hort.ncsu.edu/cucurbit/wehner/articles/book14.pdf) lists a number of cucurbits with edible shoots, including Chayote, Bitter Melon and a few types of Gourds.